# Best way to iterate through a bunch of files and search/replace text?

Tags: unix, script

I'm having some trouble doing something that should be fairly simple. Here is how I imagine it would work:

```
find . -name *.txt -exec sed 's/oldtext/newtext/g' {} > tmp \\; mv tmp {} \;
```

Unfortunately I can't sed a file and dump to itself. But I can't figure out how to dump to a temp file and then immediately mv that file. I know \\; is wrong but I can't figure out how to run one command followed by the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `-i` option in `man sed`.

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

---

Less useful but relatedly, you can also string multiple `-exec`s together; they're executed left to right.

```
tmp=$(tempfile)
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed 's/oldtext/newtext/g' '{}' > $tmp \; -exec mv $tmp '{}' \;
```

(Note the quoting of `*.txt`, `{}` and the escaping of `;` to not have them interpreted by your shell.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
find -name '*.txt' -exec ex -sc '%s/OLD/NEW/g|x' {} ';'
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `g` global replace
4. `x` save and close